# How to get variable value with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to get make an url to finish on a variable

my template is:

```
<div th:if="${!user.isEmailValidated()}" class="div-block-13">
    <div class="email_confirmed">
        <a href="/email/send/${user.getToken()}">Your email is not confirmed!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller is:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/email/send/{token}")
public String sendEmail(@PathVariable(value = "token") String token, Model model) {
    return "sent-email";
}
```

I expect url .../email/send/{value of variable}  but I get - email/send/$%7Buser.getToken()%7D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `${user.getToken()}` is not evaluated by thymeleaf because it's inside a plain `href` attribute. Use `th:href` to be able to use thymeleaf expressions: `<a th:href="@{'/email/send/' + ${user.getToken()}}">`

Comment: I am getting Could not parse as expression: "@{'/email/send/' + ${user.getToken()}"

Comment: Sorry there was a '}' missing at the end. I edited the answer.